# Header of RecyclerView has wrong focus point for zoom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a header for my zooming RecyclerView (as an itemDecoration). However, when zooming in, the header does not zoom in with the same focus point as the rest of the view. It always zooms with the focus point in the top left. How do I make the header zoom in with the same focus point?

Zooming the RecyclerView:

```
    @Override
protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    focusX = scaleGestureDetector.getFocusX();
    focusY = scaleGestureDetector.getFocusY();

    recyclerViewHeaderDecorator.setScaleFactor(scaleFactor);

    //scales the display, centered on where the user is touching the display
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);


    //Log.e(TAG, Integer.toString(viewCoordinateY));
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Header Decoration:

```
public class RecyclerViewHeaderDecorator extends ZoomRecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewDividerDecorator.class.getSimpleName();
private View header;
private float scaleFactor;
private float relativeX;
private float relativeY;


public void setScaleFactor(float scaleFactor) {
    this.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
}

public RecyclerViewHeaderDecorator(View header) {
    this.header = header;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (parent.getChildCount() > 0) {

        // Specs for parent (RecyclerView)
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        // Specs for children (headers)
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec, parent.getPaddingLeft() + parent.getPaddingRight(), header.getLayoutParams().width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec, parent.getPaddingTop() + parent.getPaddingBottom(), header.getLayoutParams().height);

        header.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

        header.layout(0, 0, header.getMeasuredWidth(), header.getMeasuredHeight());

        //keeps header on top left of RecyclerView
        float[] values = new float[9];
        Matrix matrix;
        matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        matrix.getValues(values);
        relativeX = values[2];
        relativeY = values[5];
        canvas.translate((-relativeX) / scaleFactor, (-relativeY) / scaleFactor);

        canvas.save();
        header.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    header.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int height = header.getMeasuredHeight();
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = height;
    }
}
}
```